# AsyncTask filling a ListView in a Dialog launched from a button click doesn't work right

Tags: android, dialog, arraylist, android-listview, android-asynctask

I've spent all day trying to figure this out, and it's drinving me nuts, hoping the experts around here can help me figure this out so I stop pulling my hair out.  I'm trying to fill a ListView in a Dialog window that pops up when a button is clicked.   If I put the asynctask code to start when the activity starts, everything works fine, but if I try to move the code into either where the button OnClickListener, it starts double filling the listview.

Here's the code:

In my OnCreate:

```
new LoadAllProducts().execute();
```

Which runs the following code:

```
class LoadAllProducts extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

    }

    /**
     * getting All products from url
     * */
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        // getting JSON string from URL
        JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_get_classes, "GET",
                params);

        // Check your log cat for JSON response
        Log.d("All Classes: ", json.toString());

        try {
            // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

            if (success == 1) {
                // classes found
                // Getting Array of Classes
                classes = json.getJSONArray(TAG_CLASSES);

                // looping through All Classes
                for (int i = 0; i < classes.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = classes.getJSONObject(i);

                    // Storing each json item in variable
                    String id = c.getString(TAG_CLASSID);
                    String name = c.getString(TAG_CLASSNAME);

                    // creating new HashMap
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    map.put(TAG_CLASSID, id);
                    map.put(TAG_CLASSNAME, name);

                    // adding HashList to ArrayList
                    classesList.add(map);
                }
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
            }
        });

    }

}
```

In my button's OnClickListener, I have the following:

```
onCreateDialog().show();
```

which launches the following dialog:

```
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog() {

    //Set up dialog
    dialog = new Dialog(context);
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.checkindialog);

    Button canceldialog = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btncancel);

    //Define ListView and set it's empty view in case no results come back
    this.lv = (ListView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.lvCheckin);
    this.lv.setEmptyView(dialog.findViewById(R.id.empty));

    TextView header = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.lblCheckin);
    Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),
            "fonts/roboto-light.ttf");

    header.setTypeface(tf);

    //ArrayAdapter<String> listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
    //      R.layout.checkin_item, R.id.list_content, checkinOptions);
    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(Checkin.this, classesList,
            R.layout.checkin_item, new String[] { TAG_CLASSID,
                    TAG_CLASSNAME }, new int[] { R.id.pid, R.id.name });
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> listAdapter, View arg1,
                int position, long arg3) {
            CheckIn checkin = new CheckIn();
            TextView txt = (TextView) listAdapter.getChildAt(
                    position - lv.getFirstVisiblePosition()).findViewById(
                    R.id.name);
            String CheckinMessage = Utilities.getFacebookCheckinMessage(txt
                    .getText().toString(), context);

            checkin.CheckInToFacebook(CheckinMessage, activity);

        }
    });

    canceldialog.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dialog.dismiss();

        }
    });
    return dialog;
}
```

So like I said, this works fine, except the listview only gets it's data when the activity is launched, and I'm trying to have it happen when the button gets clicked.   I've tried two things.  Moving the "onCreateDialog().show();" to the "onPostExecute" of the AsncTask, but this doesn't work right, and I've tried moving the "new LoadAllProducts().execute();" into both the ondialog create event, as well as inline with the button click listener.  Both of these only end up continually adding to the listview, instead of clearing/refreshing the listview each time.

Really hope someone can help, as I'm sure it's probably something stupid but this has been kicking my butt all day today.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Evan try overriding the protected Dialog `onCreateDialog(int id)` function for show dialog and also override `public void onPrepareDialog(int id, Dialog dialog)`. In onPrepareDialog function call `removeDialog(int id)` function this will help in creating a fresh dialog every time and remove previously cached data.